# How to create taxonomy view page using term name not term id?

Tags: url, view, drupal, alias, taxonomy

I have created a views page, in Drupal 8, of list of nodes related to a specific term. The page current url is 'taxonomy/term/%', which works fine. What I would like to do is now use the term's url alias. For example, if the term 'industry' has a url of 'taxonom/term/152' I want to change the url to 'resource/industry'. I am looking for the correct configuration on the views page to achieve this. Currently the 'Contextual Filter' is using taxonomy by id.
[Screenshots of views configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y3WZ.png)

[Screenshots of views configuration url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhq3O.png)

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I did it (D9):

1. Add a custom field to your vocabulary. I called mine "Alias for Views". I also chose to make it a required field, though I suppose you could also use rules to populate it or write a little script to do so.
2. Configure URL Aliases to use your new field in the pattern. For example vocabulary-name/alias-for-views
3. Use that field as your contextual filter in your view. Configure "when the filter value is not in the URL" using "provide a default value" and "raw value from URL." Be sure to specify the correct path component (mine is 2).
4. Setup your view as a block.
5. Navigate to Structure >> Taxonomy >> Vocabulary >> Manage Display >> Use Layout Builder >> Save >> Manage Layout
6. Add your block from views to the page.

Do a happy dance and be thankful to the Drupal community who have built such flexible and powerful tools!